# Dart dependency injection - why can't I pass an instance reference to class members?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, syntax, mobx

I'm currently writing an app using Flutter and began refactoring my state management using MobX. Since I have several stores that will communicate with each other, I attempted to "connect" these stores as suggested in the MobX best practices: https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html#combining-multiple-stores.

Create a "root" store which holds the other stores as members, each containing a reference to the root store.

For some reason I am unable to do this seemingly simple thing. I have searched a lot but couldn't find an answer.

This is basically what I want to do:

```dart
class StoreA {
  final Root _root;

  StoreA(this._root);
}

class root {
  final StoreA = StoreA(this);
}
```

The dart analyzer complains:

> Invalid reference to 'this' expression

Comment: `this` is simply not allowed inside initializers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `this` in initializers, but you could use it in a constructor, if you drop the `final` qualifier.

```
class Root {
  StoreA storeA;

  Root() {
    storeA = StoreA(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Richard Heap's answer is currently the correct answer, but in a future release of Dart which includes a non-nullable type system, you'll be able to write the following:

```dart
class StoreA {
  final Root _root;

  StoreA(this._root);
}

class root {
  late final StoreA = StoreA(this);
}
```

You can see the specification for non-nullable by default (NNBD) and related features like `late` fields at the [Dart language repository](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/nnbd/feature-specification.md).